# Clear setuptools cache in pyramid?

Tags: python, caching, pyramid, setuptools

I am pretty new to python and pyramid. I am working on pyramid application that I run with the following command:

```
pserve development.ini
```

When I make some changes and restart the server (kill it and run it again) it keeps the old versions of the files in cache.

I have noticed that I can clean the cache by re-installing the application with

```
python setup.py install
```

but I am sure that there is a nicer way for this?

I have noticed that the cache files are kept in the build folder:

```
build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `python setup.py install`, use `python setup.py develop`. This will link your application's directory into the site-packages without creating a separate "installed" source tree.

Comment: thanks, works fine now... did not realize that install is for production only